# Swift difficulty understanding UINavigationController & navigationController re: presentingViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

My code works, but I'm trying to understand it.  It's a bit of code used to manage a "Cancel" button that can return from either a "Show" segue (presented when user clicks on a table view cell for editing) or a "Present Modally" segue (when the user clicks a "+" bar button item to add a new cell to the table view). Diagram below. I'm getting confused by UINavigationController and the navigationController property. Apologies if I'm missing something very obvious.

```
// Apple says below is nil if neither the current view controller nor any of its ancestors were presented modally
let isPresentingInAddMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController
if isPresentingInAddMode {
    // Modal segues need to be dismissed
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    // But Show segues are "popped" off of a stack of controllers.
        navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Here's what I am not understanding:
-   If I've arrived at the Detail View Controller via a "Show" segue, pause during execution, and option-click on navigationController, Xcode says that it's a UINavigationController? And if I pause execution inside the else condition & use the debugger to:
po navigationController! == nil
-   Xcode says it this evaluates to false, so navigationController is a valid UINavigationController.

So why doesn't

```
presentingViewController is UINavigationController
```

equate to true in the topmost statement when I've presented using a "Show"?
Perhaps I'm not understanding "present".  Is presenting something that only happens with modal segues, so there's no presentingViewController?
And if I look back at my storyboard (see diagram below) one of the ancestors for the Detail View Controller is a table view controller that has a navigation controller embedded in it given Apple's definition of presentingViewController, shouldn't: 
presentingViewController is UINavigationController
Be true in this situation, too?

And would:

```
presentingViewController != nil
```

achieve the same result or is there an important reason to verify the presentingViewController is a UINavigationController?

Thanks much for anyone kind enough to help me parse this out.
John

[image]

[image]

The "ShowDetail" segue is a "Show" segue originating from the table view cell.  The "AddItem" segue is of kind "Present Modally" and is originating from the "+" add bar button item.

It's likely not necessary to see the prepare for segue code in the table view controller, but if you're curious:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {  // is this the "ShowDetail" segue? and if it is...
        // ... get the IndexPath for the row the user clicked on (the selected row)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController // downcast the destination as the specific class DetailViewController
        // Get the to do item that the user clicked on
        let selectedToDo = toDoArray[indexPath.row]
        // Pass selectedToDo to the toDoItem variable in our destinationViewController
        destinationViewController.toDoItem = selectedToDo
    }
}
```

Comment: please add code where you call the ViewControllers

Comment: put shot code snippets between two of this char: ` (backtick)

Comment: Hi - there is a Show segue - "ShowDetail" is its identifier.  "AddItem" is called from the "+" add bar button item, while "ShowDetail" is called from the table view cell.  I'll add the "prepare(for segue:) code for the table view controller above, but it shouldn't matter re: understanding the UINavigationController vs. navigationController, should it? Thx

Comment: Yes - poor choice of Identifier name by me, but "ShowDetail" is the identifier.  The segue is of Kind: attribute is "Show (e.g. Push)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps I'm not understanding "present".

Perhaps. Let's consult the chart:

[image]

There are two commonly used built-in segues:

- Show, formerly known as Push. If used in a UINavigationController situation, as intended, calls `pushViewController`. The pushed view controller has a `navigationController`. The return is performed by calling `popViewController`.
- Present, formerly known as Modal. Calls `presentViewController` (now called `present`). The presented view controller has a `presentingViewController`. The return is performed by calling `dismiss`.

However, there's a complication that can confuse you: if `show` is used *not* in a UINavigationController situation, instead of the universe exploding as expected, it magically turns itself into `present`.

Comment: Unfortunately, people in speaking informally do very often say "present" when they mean "push", so you have to watch out.

Comment: This was great! Very helpful.  So modals always have a presentingViewController.  Is it appropriate to use either of these two statements to test if a view controller is modal? "presentingViewController != nil" or "presentingViewController is UINavigationController"?

Comment: Almost. Look more carefully at what I said. Asking whether `self.presentingViewController != nil` is how to learn whether `self` is a presented view controller. Asking whether `self.navigationController != nil` is how to learn whether `self` is a pushed view controller. — In general, however, you will never _not_ know this, so in practice the question doesn't usually arise.

Comment: Thanks again. This code confusion comes from my attempt to learn Swift using Apple'sFoodTracker app. Looks like the ShowDetail misname was learned from Cupertino :) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1

Comment: No. Look more carefully at the screen shot. `"ShowDetail"` is merely an arbitrary string here: the segue's string _identifier_. It could just as well have been `"RevealTheDetailsToMe"`. The segue _itself_ is a Show segue, as you can see from the Kind pop-up just below.

Comment: Thanks - just bought Kindle version of your "Programming iOS 10: Dive Deep into Views, View Controllers, and Frameworks".  Your kindness on StackOverflow pays off :) Best, J